# Is there a way I run this script?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a large dataset that I intend generating a sample of 10% from it to run my machine learning model 20 times. To test how it will work, I decided to use `iris` dataset to try it. First, I split the dataset into training and testing dataset and then used a `While loop` to try a simple loop but it doesn't seem to work as I got an error message. Please is there something I missed out?

```
      ### partitioning dataset

      part <- sample(1:150, size = 100, replace = F)
      training <- iris[part,]
      testing <- iris[-part,]

      ## using a loop 
      n <-1
      while (n<6) {
            Train(n)<-training[sample(1:100,0.3*nrow(training), replace = F),]
            fit <- randomForest(Species~., data = Train(n))
            pred <- predict(fit, testing)
            confusionMatrix(pred, testing$Species))
            n <-n+1
      }
```

The error message I got is

```
      Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: `confusionMatrix` has two `))`?

Comment: `Train(n)` is a function call, both lines where it shows up are syntax errors, remove the `(n)` part.

Comment: Thanks @user2974951. I've corrected it and the new error is ```Error in Train(n) <- training[sample(1:100, 0.3 * nrow(training), replace = F),  : 
  could not find function "Train<-"```

Comment: Thanks @Rui Barradas. If I remove the ```n```, don't you think the loop will become endless? How will I make it stop?

Comment: What exactly does `n` do in the `Train()` call? If `Train()` is not a function then you do need to remove `(n)`, which will overwrite the Train variable each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the loop corrected and tested.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(randomForest)
  library(caret)
})

set.seed(2022)
part <- sample(1:150, size = 100, replace = FALSE)
training <- iris[part,]
testing <- iris[-part,]

## using a loop 
result <- vector("list", 6L)
n <- 1L
while(n < 6L) {
  Train <- training[sample(1:100, 0.3*nrow(training), replace = FALSE), ]
  fit <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data = Train)
  pred <- predict(fit, testing)
  result[[n]] <- confusionMatrix(pred, testing$Species)
  n <- n + 1L
}

## see the first result
result[[1]]
#> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#> 
#>             Reference
#> Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
#>   setosa         16          0         0
#>   versicolor      0         11         1
#>   virginica       0          3        19
#> 
#> Overall Statistics
#>                                           
#>                Accuracy : 0.92            
#>                  95% CI : (0.8077, 0.9778)
#>     No Information Rate : 0.4             
#>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1.565e-14       
#>                                           
#>                   Kappa : 0.8778          
#>                                           
#>  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA              
#> 
#> Statistics by Class:
#> 
#>                      Class: setosa Class: versicolor Class: virginica
#> Sensitivity                   1.00            0.7857           0.9500
#> Specificity                   1.00            0.9722           0.9000
#> Pos Pred Value                1.00            0.9167           0.8636
#> Neg Pred Value                1.00            0.9211           0.9643
#> Prevalence                    0.32            0.2800           0.4000
#> Detection Rate                0.32            0.2200           0.3800
#> Detection Prevalence          0.32            0.2400           0.4400
#> Balanced Accuracy             1.00            0.8790           0.9250
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

There's nothing to gain with a `while` loop versus a `for` loop, you are manually incrementing `n` and that's what `for` loops are meant for.

The equivalent `for` loop is the following.

```
result <- vector("list", 6L)
for(n in 1:6) {
  Train <- training[sample(1:100, 0.3*nrow(training), replace = FALSE), ]
  fit <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data = Train)
  pred <- predict(fit, testing)
  result[[n]] <- confusionMatrix(pred, testing$Species)
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks so much. Before you posted the ```For loop``` equivalent, I tried it and it worked. I am grateful @Rui Barradas